# Why can't my friend join my Minecraft world even though we are on the same version and platform?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, networking, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

Me and my friend don't play on Realms, but we can join each others' worlds on Minecraft Pocket Edition. The thing is, he can always easily access my world, but sometimes I can't get into his world. It's odd actually, once when I was trying to join his world the screen just went blank.

Instead of loading the server/world, where you can see the dirt background and it says `Locating server...`, it doesn't show the `Locating server...` message, it only displays the dirt background. Then it says: `Unable to connect to world`, even though we both have the same version of Minecraft Pocket Edition.

My question is: why can't I join his world?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Minecraft Pocket Edition multiplayer has always been fairly unreliable. It's improved in recent times, but still.....

Here's some things to try (do this on both devices if possible):

- Check both devices are connected to the same local network. Make sure you can open websites on both devices. Sounds stupid, but a lost connection is probably the issue.
- Close MCPE, open the app switcher on your device, remove it from the list by swiping it away, then open the app and try again.
- Turn the device completely off, then on again, then open the app and try again.
- With an iOS device, hold down all the buttons (home, power and volume) on the device at the same time. After some time, the screen will go blank. Continue holding the buttons until you see the Apple logo. Release the buttons straightaway when that appears. Open the app and try again.
- Try again later, or even the next day. It sounds terrible but does in fact work sometimes.
- (Most drastic option, last resort, all MCPE worlds on that device will be erased unless you back them up.) Uninstall MCPE and reinstall.

Let me know how that goes for you.

Answer (score -3):

This was either a problem with your network or the server running the minecraft multiplayer. Just wait and the server will probably be up soon.

Comment: If you are not sure about the answer, then *please* post as comments, it's not like people are always unexpectedly right every time they guess.